# How to insert custom function in tinymce,

Tags: function, tinymce

i'd like to know how i can make my custom function in tinymce. assumed that my function named as A. 
The function is inserting form html tag such as ", etc". From this function (button) people who dont know even any tag of HTML, can insert the tag without editing the text mannualy.
i want A appear as a button in tinymce toolbar.My function insert a HTML tag in the document that people edit it,by pressing the button.
so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this short tutorial on howto write an own plugin](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aCreate_plugin/3.x) (containing own functions).